# The difference between $V=kQ/r$ and $V=ED$ ($V$ is electric potential)?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, capacitance, gauss-law

I realize $V=kQ/r$ is the electric potential of a point charge while the other one is the electric potential in a uniform electric field, but in the first case the distance (radius) is inversely proportional to electric potential while in the 2nd case it's proportional? How can both be right at the same time?

Comment: I'm not sure what the confusion is, you answered your question in the first sentence?

Comment: I'm quite sure this has been asked many times before.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uniform Electric Field](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/173631/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Electric Field vs Distance (Contradiction)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/493344/)