# Why is the electric potential for a point charge is $V=kQ/r$ but for the capacitance of parallel plate , the electric potential is $V=E*D$?

Tags: electrostatics, potential, capacitance, gauss-law

From what I've learned since now, I always knew electric potential is inversely proportional to radius or distance for a point charge, but I've come across the electric potential in a parallel plate capacitor and it says that electric potential decreases when the distance between two plates decrease, so how can electric potential be inversely proportional in the first case but proportional to the distance in the second case?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Electric Field vs Distance (Contradiction)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/493344/)

Comment: yes somewhat, I can find the answer from here, Thanks!